# Make Nvidia X server settings persistent across reboots

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg

How do i keep my Nvidia settings persistent across reboots.

The issue lies within the `force composition pipeline` settings on the x server configuration. And the current solution is to enable the `Full composition pipeline` option in the **X server Display Configuration**. 
Now my real issue to trying to keep the X server persistent on power off and start up. 
So far I tried to run `nvidia-settings` as root and save the configuration to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but either of those fail. And `nvidia-settings --load-config-only` dose not work either. Is there any other options available (* with `nvidia-settings --load-config-only` I just tried, haven rebooted yet.)
(** just tried `nvidia-settings --load-config-only` dose not work)

Answer (score 0):

The setting(s) can be applied across reboots by first using "force full composition pipeline" in the X server settings and saving the configuration in the Xconfig file with the nvidia X server settings.